# How to connect ZKTeco attendance to google sheet or online php server

Tags: php, google-sheets, zkteco

I don't have any idea of it how can i get attendance data directly to google sheet from ZKTeco attendance device. I searched many way to connect to php server but there is no clear information, how can I get access to the device attendance log. There also no HTTP request from the device also. So can any share there experience and how can I solve that issue ? I am using ZKTeco K40 and F18

Answer (score 1):

You need to develop a program that calls the [ZKTeco web API](https://camsunit.com/application/biometric-web-api.html) and have an available server that post your users' data.

After you have the data available in JSON, you can use the [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) you can call in Apps Script within your Google Sheets to display the information in a spreadsheet in this way

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
var content = response.getContentText()
var json = JSON.parse(content)
```